# Can a node that exists in an hierarchy contain its own specific transformation

Tags: nodes, transformation, skeletal-animation

Let's say I have an hierarchy of nodes, each with its own local transformations, that eventually carries over to its children.

Is there mathematically a way to apply some transformation to a specific node in the hierarchy, without it being applied to any children of this node?

Answer (score 1):

Take the inverse of the transformation you wish to apply, Then apply it to the children of the node. So effectively you have moved the node independent of its children. (If you need to do this often, then the question is why the children are considered children, maybe they should be siblings).

Comment: This actually happens in real time. I have specific nodes that need to act slightly different, otherwise I get into double-transformation situations, where children are transformed both themselves, and then also by the parent. I guess the only real solution is to add identifiers to my nodes so I can know which one each is....